# INSERT fails on EF 4.1 Code First Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with MVC3 Tools Update, and EF 4.1 Code First to scaffold my application's database.

Database CRUD operations work fine when testing locally and on a local database. It is not until I migrate the database to web host's SQL Server 2008 R2 and target that hosted database in my connection string that all INSERT operations fail.

Whenever I try to add a new record I get this error: [I]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'DB_23378_bloomlmsdata.dbo.Courses'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.[/I]

My data models all specify a Primary Identity Key like so:

```
[Key]
public int Id {get; set;}
...
```

And in the local database that gets scaffolded, I see a non-nullable Primary Identity Key in each table.

I read somewhere that Entity Framework, when performing an INSERT operation to the database it will first try to insert a record with a null value as the Primary Key. I do not know how to override this behaviour. Also, this does not seem to be a common problem and people usually only run in to this when they use something different than an IDENTITY key. For the record, I had the same problem with EF CodeFirst CTP5 before EF 4.1 was released.

I have been troubleshooting this for 4 weeks.. My web host is up to date with the technology I am using in my application and database. When I try to get help, they are telling me it is a coding issue but my code checks out. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using auto generated id values (Identity) in the database?

Comment: Does it work when you issue an INSERT command from SQL Server Management Studio? You could also test `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` to execute a raw SQL INSERT command, just to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @Siva - I have tried that once already but thank you. @Slauma - Going to try this out as soon as I can, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the IsIdentity property of the Id column, it should be set to yes. EF doesn't pass a value for the identity column on an insert because it should be auto-generated by the database.